# Insert variables into a given URL without changing quotes

Tags: php, html, regex, string, url

I have a URL

```
http://url.com/api/cover?multi={"isbn":"VARIABLE_HERE"}&type=medium&keywords=VARIABLE_HERE
```

This url is given by API that I want to use and nothing can be changed on it, only `VARIABLE_HERE` must be replaced by a variable.

So first one is `$isbn` and second is `$search_term`.

When I try to insert those two variables like this

```
$url = "http://url.com/api/cover?multi={"isbn":"$isbn"}&type=medium&keywords=$search_term";
```

I get error since `"` are causing trouble. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes by using `\`:

```
$url = "http://url.com/api/cover?multi={\"isbn\":\"$isbn\"}&type=medium&keywords=$search_term";
```

Or simply use single quotes and concatenate the variables

```
$url = 'http://url.com/api/cover?multi={"isbn":"'.$isbn.'"}&type=medium&keywords='.$search_term;
```

Comment: I have tried using \ but API rejected it, I guess it has very strict policy for the url. Second solution works. Thank you.

Comment: The \ will not be sent to the API, it will tell PHP to treat the double quotes as a part of the string, if you found this answer helpful feel free to mark it as accepted.

Comment: I will accept it as soon as SO will let me...Can't until next 5 minutes..